# Событие dropEvent() в qt 6.3.2 срабатывает 2 раза

Tags: c++, qt, drag-n-drop, qt6

Перетаскивание начинается в к кастомном виджете его принимает QGraphicsView, чтобы добавть новый элемент, но добавляется 2 элемента, тк событие происходит дважды. Сначала как отпускаю мышку, потом как только мышь двинется. Я думал что как то не так завершаю события Enter Leave и Move, но как бы я их не выкручивал ничего не исчезает. Ну только то что их наличие обязательно иначе дроп вообще не произойдет.
Кастомный виджет:

```cpp
void ElemItem::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
        auto *drag = new QDrag(this);

        auto *mimeData = new QMimeData();
        mimeData->setProperty("width", "50");
        mimeData->setProperty("height", "100");

        drag->setMimeData(mimeData);
        drag->exec();

        Qt::DropAction result = drag->exec(Qt::MoveAction);
        qDebug() << "Drop action result: " << result;
        if (result == Qt::MoveAction) {
        }
    }
}
```

QGraphicsView based class

```cpp
void EditorView::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event) {
    setBackgroundBrush(Qt::black);
    event->accept();
}

void EditorView::dragLeaveEvent(QDragLeaveEvent *event) {
    setBackgroundBrush(Qt::white);
    event->accept();
}

void EditorView::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event) {
    event->acceptProposedAction();
}

void EditorView::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event) {
    if (event->isAccepted()) {
        qDebug() << "accepted";
        return;
    }

    auto w = event->mimeData()->property("width");
    auto h = event->mimeData()->property("height");

    if (!w.canConvert<int>() || !h.canConvert<int>()) {
        event->accept();
        return;
    }

    auto *e = new EMSItem(w.toInt(), h.toInt());

    _scene->addItem(e);

    qDebug() << "adding" << event->isAccepted();

    e->moveBy(event->position().x() - w.toInt() / 2, event->position().y() - h.toInt() / 2);

    event->acceptProposedAction();
    QGraphicsView::dropEvent(event);
}
```

[image: результат перетаскивания]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На эту тему в `Qt` есть хороший пример -  `PuzzleWidget`. Я в Вашем коде нашел два подозрительных момента:

- наличие двух вызовов drag->exec():
  `drag->exec();`
  и сразу после него
  `Qt::DropAction result = drag->exec(Qt::MoveAction);`
- Вызов (по всей вероятности родительского) `QGraphicsView::dropEvent(event);` в переопределенном `EditorView::dropEvent`.

Из моего опыта - такое случается, если Вы добавляете элемент на сцену по нажатию `mousePressEvent` и по отпусканию `mouseReleaseEvent` ЛКМ.
Или Вы перетаскиваете модифицированный элемент (`drag`), а затем еще и добавляете его - `addItem`.
Т.к. вырваны только куски кода, то могу только догадываться. Если выложите больше - могу попробовать запустить и отладить.

Comment: тупанул я знатно